# How to pass variables into a callback function in matlab (with addlistener)

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a continuously updating slider...

```
hsl = uicontrol(...); % Slider initializing stuff
vars=struct('hsl', hsl, 'x', x, 'y', y); % A bunch of stuff that my callback needs
set(hsl,'Callback',{@hsl_callback,vars});

addlistener(hsl,'ContinuousValueChange',@hsl_callback);
```

Here's the problem. If I leave it like that, I get the error "not enough input arguments" for the callback.

If I change the line to this:

```
addlistener(hsl,'ContinuousValueChange',@(vars)hsl_callback);
```

then I get the error "too many input arguments."

Is this not possible, or am I getting the syntax wrong?

If it helps, my callback function has this structure:

```
function hsl_callback(~,~,vars)
    k = get(vars.hsl,'Value');
    % plot x, y scaled by k
end
```

Comment: try `addlistener(hsl,'ContinuousValueChange',@() hsl_callback(vars));`?

Comment: I just did, but it still says that there are too many input arguments.

Comment: I have also tried `addlistener(hsl,'ContinuousValueChange',@{hsl_callback,vars});`, which doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would avoid using `vars` to store your data. The slider handle can be passed directly in your callback, and `x` and `y` may be stored in the `UserData` property. This gives you the ability to change `x` and `y` dynamically, if needed. Change your callback method declaration to:

```
function hsl_callback(hObject,eventdata)
  % Retrieve k and vars
  k = get ( hObject , 'Value' );
  vars = get ( hObject , 'UserData' );

  % Plot x,y scaled by k
  ...
end
```

Then, I would change slider creation to:

```
% Define x and y.
vars = struct('x',x,'y',y);

% Create slider, assigning vars to UserData.
hSlider = uicontrol('Sytle','Slider',...,'UserData',vars);

% Assign the callback method, executed whenever the slider is released.
set(hSlider,'Callback',@hsl_callback);

% Assign the listener, executing whenever the slider value changes.
hListener = addlistener(hSlider,'ContinuousValueChange',@(src,eventdata)hsl_callback);
```

Depending on your version, you may have to use this instead:

```
hListener = addlistener ( hSlider , 'Value' , 'PostSet' , @(src,eventdata)hsl_callback );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this seems like a better way to handle passing in data. However, I'm still getting the same error on the addlistener line- not enough input arguments.

Comment: Oops, this is the working code: `hListener = addlistener(hSlider,'ContinuousValueChange',@hsl_callback);`